# Enable/Disable user not working in Keycloak

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am writing a functionality which would disable a user through Keycload admin client APIs.

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeyCloakConnectionProvider.getConnection();

UserResource userResource = 
    keycloak.realm(KeyCloakConnectionProvider.SSO_REALM).users().get(userId);

UserRepresentation ur = userResource.toRepresentation();

ur.setEnabled(false);   
userResource.update(ur); // This is returning error as 501 Not Implemented.
```

Keycload application version is 7.0.1, Admin client version is 7.0.1 as well. Any solution?

on calling the userResource.update(userRepresentation) -- throws an "501 Not Implemented" Error.

What could be the possible cause.